# QGIS: use Python to remove overlap area between polygons of the same layer

Tags: python, qgis

I am trying to create a plug-in to remove the overlap area between polygons of the same layer and I would like to do this by deleting from polygons (after subdivision of the boundaries) the polygons completely contained in others. To do this I use QgsGeometryEngine.contains but, for some reason, it never seems to have a positive response: the result is always a new layer with correctly segmented polygens but also overlapping ones.

```
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    polygons = [ feat.geometry().asWkt() for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

    shapely_polygons = [ loads(pol) for pol in polygons ]

    rings = [ LineString(pol.exterior.coords) for pol in shapely_polygons ]

    union = unary_union(rings)

    new_intersections = [ geom.wkt for geom in polygonize(union) ]

    epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

    uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

    mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'new_polygons','memory')

    prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

    feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(new_intersections)) ]
    feats_2 = []
    noAdd = []
    
    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
        feat.setAttributes([i])
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(new_intersections[i]))

    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
      polygon_geometry_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(feat.geometry().constGet())
      for ii, feat_2 in enumerate(feats):
       if i != ii and polygon_geometry_engine.contains(feat_2.geometry().constGet()):
        noAdd.append(ii)

    for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
     if i not in noAdd:
      feats_2.append(feat)
    
    prov.addFeatures(feats_2)

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

[image]

Comment: I simplify the question because I really need help. The code divides well the polygons that overlap but it seems that "polygon_geometry_engine.contains" does not work: the result I get is always all the polygons

Comment: Are all of the polygons in the same shapefile? It

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what the desired output is.  Are you trying to delete only those polygons that are completely contained?  If part of the polygon is contained within another, are you trying to delete it? Or simply clip the portion that is contained?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
polygons = [feature for feature in layer.getFeatures()]
layer.startEditing()
for poly in polygons:
    poly_geo = poly.geometry()
    for poly2 in polygons:
        if poly2 != poly:
            poly2_geo = poly2.geometry()
            if poly2_geo.contains(poly_geo):
                layer.deleteFeature(poly.id())
layer.commitChanges()
```

This will only delete features that are fully contained within another feature.
[image]